# Keydown works with a second keyboard click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing my own search box, here's the code:

```js
document.querySelector('.header-search input').addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  if (this.value === "") {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.remove('reset');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.add('reset');
  }
})
document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.header-search input').value = "";
  this.classList.remove('reset');
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.header-search input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

.header-search-reset {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.header-search-reset.reset {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="button" class="header-search-reset">X</button>
</div>
```

And this code works well, but why does the button only appear after a second click on the keyboard.

Comment: The `keydown` event is triggered before the content of your input element has changed hence `this.value` will be empty.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Comment: Use `input` like in connexos answer.

Comment: Just a little showcase: https://jsfiddle.net/0udsLtjz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `input` event instead of `keydown` (because the value of an input only changes after `keydown` and `keypressed` listeners have been processed already):

```js
document.querySelector('.header-search input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (this.value === "") {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.remove('reset');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.add('reset');
  }
})
document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.header-search input').value = "";
  this.classList.remove('reset');
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.header-search input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

.header-search-reset {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.header-search-reset.reset {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="button" class="header-search-reset">X</button>
</div>
```

Also, this even works if you **drag** marked text into the input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use keyup as an event listener instead of keydown. Otherwise your this.value is empty after the first keystroke. Check the console log.

```js
document.querySelector('.header-search input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  console.log(this.value)
  if (this.value === "") {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.remove('reset');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.add('reset');
  }
})
document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.header-search input').value = "";
  this.classList.remove('reset');
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.header-search input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

.header-search-reset {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.header-search-reset.reset {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="button" class="header-search-reset">X</button>
</div>
```

However: As pointed out by connexo this won't trigger if you drag text into the input field. Use input as event if you need that.

Comment: While this works, it won't cover dragging text into the input. But thanks for pointing out that `keyup` is being processed after `input`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you check the value before it's changed.

```
document.querySelector('.header-search input').addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  if (this.value === "") {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.remove('reset');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.header-search-reset').classList.add('reset');
  }
})
```

What's happening:

- You press the A key on your keybord.
- The browser has detected a button has been pressed.
- Things happend so fast that when the browser gets the value of *this* : nothing had the time to change yet, your finger is still on your A key.

Because you check the value before the key letter is computed, the value has not changed. You simply need to add a listener at keyup, and then magic will happend. :)

- You press the A key.
- Your finger is lifting off the key (and it's value get computed in .header-search input).
- The browser detects a keyup action.
- The browser inspect the value of this : the value had the time to change according what you pressed and your keyboard!

Comment: _"...before the key letter is computed"_ - There's nothing to "compute". At the moment the `keydown` event handler is executed it is already clear which key triggered the event (`event.keyCode` / `event.code`). Only the value of the input element has not been updated yet.